# decrypt non alphabetical characters in python ceasar cypher

Tags: python, encryption

I found online a working script to try on ceaser cypher, I modified it a bit to be able to decrypt and it's working well for both sides except one detail:

whenever it's a special character (non alphabetical) such as: , . ! () ect... it encrypts it like a letter (fine and normal I guess) but once decrypted, these special characters are transformed into a letter, of course it's still kinda readable, but not fully decrypted as it should.

I'm pretty new to encryption, I've looked arround a bit but don't seem to find any solutions so any insight will be helpful

here is the script:

```
def encrypt(text,s):
result = ""

for i in range(len(text)):
    char = text[i]
    
    if (char.isupper()):
        result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
  
    else:
        result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
return result



def decrypt(text,s):
result = ""

for i in range(len(text)):
    char = text[i]
    
    if (char.isupper()):
        result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
  
    else:
        result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
return result



def selection():
    choice = input('Enter selection:\n1 = Encrypt Message\n2 = Decrypt Message\n\n')
    choice = int(choice)
    if choice == 1:
        text = input('Enter message:\n')
        s = input('Enter encryption key number: ')
        s = int(s)
        encrypt(text,s)
        print ("Encrypted message: " + encrypt(text,s)+"\n")
        selection()

    elif choice == 2:
       text = input('Enter encrypted message:\n')
       s = input('Enter decryption key number: ')
       s = int(s)
       decrypt(text,s)
       print ("Decrypted message: " + encrypt(text,s)+"\n")
       selection()

   else:
       print("Error! Enter 1 (Message Encryption) or 2 (Message Decryption)")
       selection()

selection()
```

Comment: `encrypt` uses as alphabet the 26 ASCII characters from 65 (0x41) inclusive (i.e. all upper case letters) and from 97 (0x61) inclusive (i.e. all lower case letters). Other characters are not allowed and if they are used, decryption will not work. There is also a bug in `decrypt`: In both, the `if` and `else` condition, `s` must not be added, but subtracted. If you also want to include special characters, the alphabet must be defined accordingly.

Comment: In addition, `decrypt` (and not `encrypt`) must be called in the `selection` method during decryption (within the `print` command). The preceding `decrypt` call is not taken into account and can be removed (the latter applies analogously to encryption).

Comment: thx a lot, I've modified everything accordingly to your answer. How can I include special characters in my alphabet? I've seen script where people were doing one  alphabet with both upper & lower case such as: alphabet = "abc....xyzABC...XYZ"

Comment: so should I include the special characters in this variable? Because you mentionned that others characters are not allowed. If I correctly understood, by creating an alphabet and including the special chararcters inside, it will bypass the impossibility to encrypt and decrypt them because of the ASCII format, right?

Comment: _I've seen script where people were doing one alphabet with both upper & lower case such as: alphabet = "abc....xyzABC...XYZ"_: The way you define the alphabet depends on the logic you implement. If you define the alphabet this way, the rest of the code must match, which is not the case for the posted code. Here the alphabet is defined by the start ASCII value and the number of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because your encrption and decription "know" just alphabetical chars.
your script isn't generic to all computer chars.
try this code for ceaser cypher

```
def encrypt(plain_text, key):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(i) + key) for i in plain_text])



def decrypt(encryped_text, key):
    return encrypt(encryped_text, -key)


def selection():
    while True:
        choice = input('Enter selection:\n1 = Encrypt Message\n2 = Decrypt Message\n\n')
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            plain_text = input('Enter message:\n')
            key = int(input('Enter encryption key number: '))
            encrypted_text = encrypt(plain_text, key)
            print(f"Encrypted message: {encrypted_text}")
        elif choice == 2:
            encrypted_text = input('Enter encrypted message:\n')
            key = int(input('Enter decryption key number: '))
            plain_text = decrypt(encrypted_text, key)
            print(f"Decrypted message: {plain_text}")
        else:
            print("Error! Enter 1 (Message Encryption) or 2 (Message Decryption)")

selection()
```

I also changed the decrypt function to be the opposite of encryptin because ceaser cypher is Symmetric encryption, in other words, the user give the encrypt and decrypt the same key in both sides.